# SAS input json into HTML

Tags: html, json, sas, put, sas-macro

Im creating an HTML file from SAS like the following

```
data _null_;
file './test.html';
put '<DOCTYPE html>';
put '<html>';
put '<script>'
put '</script>'
put '</html>'
```

The problem is that I need to take a SAS dataset, convert it to JSON format and insert it into the HTML file. The pseudo code is:

```
data _null_;
file './test.html';
put '<DOCTYPE html>';
put '<html>';
put '<script>';
sasDataFrame -> to Json
put 'console.log(sasDataFrame)';
put '</script>'
put '</html>'
```

I know that proc JSON allows me to convert SAS dataset to Json, but i don't know how to embed the string result into an HTML through this sort of put statement.

Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Create the JSON file as a text file using PROC JSON or whatever method you want.  Then write the contents of that file into your HTML file.

So let's assume you have pointed the fileref JSON to file with the JSON text in it.

Now first write the header information, then the contents of the file, then the trailing information.

With your simple example you could do it all in one data step. Just read the lines from the JSON text file and write them to the HTML file you are creating.

```
data _null_;
  file './test.html';
  if _n_=1 then put
    '<DOCTYPE html>'
  / '<html>'
  / '<script>'
  ;
  if eof then put 
     '</script>'
  /  '</html>'
  ;
  infile json end=eof;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

For more complex file generation you can use multiple data steps to construct the HTML file.  Just use MOD option on the FILE statement to append text to an existing file instead of making a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming web content like this is an antipattern!!

Rather than fiddle around with put statements, why not serve your index.html through the web server, and send the data from SAS directly as a pure JSON payload?

Here's a repo we created that will let you talk to SAS from frontend:  https://github.com/sasjs/adapter

And here's another one with a ready-made web app you can use as a starting point:  https://github.com/sasjs/minimal-seed-app

Whilst plugging SASjs (an open source tool my team created) I'll also point out that by using this approach you can easily deploy and run your web app on Viya and Base SAS as well as SAS 9 BI.  It'll also run much faster and be easier to maintain.